# Base a ControlTemplate on another ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

I know there must be an easy answer to this but I can't find it.

I've got a button style called `HoverButton`.

```
<Style x:Key="HoverButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

I then want to create another 'derived' style that is based on a `HoverButton` with specific content. I've reduced the complexity of the above style here, but it's complex enough that I don't want to copy and paste it.

```
<Style x:Key="CloseButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource HoverButton}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Path Width="8" Height="8" Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Data="M0,0 L8,8 M8,0 L0,8" StrokeThickness="2" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This doesn't work - "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first." It seems like I need to redefine the `Template` property of the derived style, but somehow reference the base style's template.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll assume that the TargetType being missing on the second Style was just a slip (so i added it)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot base templates on one-another, but this error could easily be resolved. Just create an equivalent `ContentTemplate` instead of setting the `Content`. That way one `Path` is created for each button, and not one for all buttons (which is not allowed).

Comment: That's it. I knew it would be simple. Thanks. Now I've just got to work out *why* it works ;)

Comment: @TimRogers: Did i not explain that sufficiently? Templates are, as the name implies, building plans of what is to be created, they are not discreet objects, and all UI elements can only be the child of one parent. Using templates every button creates its own content, if you however set the content in a style only one object is created which is used everywhere.

Comment: You did explain it well. I didn't really appreciate the difference between control templates and content templates, but I guess I do now.  The `Template` property defines a template for the whole control, whereas `ContentTemplate` just defines the template used by the inner `ContentPresenter`. Simple.